# No muestra los resultados de la consulta

Tags: sql

hice una consulta via script php y muestra los resultados, pero la hago directamente a la tabla con pgadmin 3, y si me muestra los resultados, no entiendo el tipo de error,

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Exactamente cómo quieres que te ayudemos si no pones el código que estás usando? Así con esos datos puede ser un problema en la conexión a la bd, un problema de permisos sobre la tabla, un error sintáctico en la consulta, que no has instalado bien la librería, ... Cualquiera de esos problemas debe estar registrándose en algún sitio o puedes capturarlos y escribirlos por pantalla

Comment: El error esta en la linea 3 del php, y la 4 variable del sql... fuera de la broma, no podemos ayudarte sin saber que estas haciendo en cada lugar...

Comment: $sql1 = "SELECT MAX(h.codperi) AS ultperi FROM sno_hperiodo AS h 
 WHERE h.anocur = '2023' AND h.codnom NOT IN ('0021', '0022', '0023', '0024', '0025') GROUP BY h.anocur ORDER BY h.anocur               LIMIT 1"; no me da el resultado